# displaying a file whose name is a variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var t = new Date();
var m = t.getMonth()+1;
var d = t.getDate();

mm = m.toString();
dd = d.toString();

var textfile = mm + dd;

[want to display the text file here]

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I display a text file named 'textfile'?

I have a text file for each day of the year.  All of them are different.  They're on the server in the same directory where the javascript is.  When someone goes to the page I want the file corresponding to the date to be displayed.

Comment: Please provide more context. Where/what is this textfile you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is available in the server, then use

```
window.location.href = textfile;
```